# How to countdown from a NSDate and display it in hours and minutes

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nstimer

I'm trying to countdown from a NSDate and display it in hours and minutes. Like this: 1h:18min

At the moment my date is updating to a UILabel and counting down but displaying like this:

[image: timer countdown label]

Here's the code I'm using. A startTimer method and a updateLabel method

```
 - (void)startTimer {
        // Set the date you want to count from

    // convert date string to date then set to a label
    NSDateFormatter *dateStringParser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateStringParser setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z"];

    NSDate *date = [dateStringParser dateFromString:deadlineDate];

    NSDateFormatter *labelFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [labelFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH-dd-MM-yyyy"];

    NSDate *countdownDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    countdownDate = date; 

    // Create a timer that fires every second repeatedly and save it in an ivar
    NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] init];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)updateLabel {

    // convert date string to date then set to a label
    NSDateFormatter *dateStringParser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateStringParser setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z"];

    NSDate *date = [dateStringParser dateFromString:deadlineDate];

    NSDateFormatter *labelFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [labelFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH-dd-MM"];


    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceNow]; ///< Assuming this is in the future for now.


    self.deadlineLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timeInterval];
}
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval 
  {
    NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)interval;
    NSInteger seconds = ti % 60;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds];
  }
```

Comment: thanks! how would I then use that method to apply it to the     self.deadlineLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timeInterval];

Comment: simple, create another NSString and pass the return string of this stringFromTimeInterval by passing interval to it, and print that timeinterval2!

Answer (score 1):

Since you use NSTimeInterval ,you are getting the time interval ,ie the difference, in seconds, to display it in hours and minutes you need to apply mathematics logic and convert it!
You many need a few loops to do it.

try this

Regards